# Eclipse won't start

Tags: release-juno, release-hera, applications, eclipse

I get this error when trying to run Eclipse. This is after installing Eclipse from the App Center on a fresh install of Elementary 5.1:

```
!SESSION Thu Oct 01 22:09:06 CDT 2020 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2020-10-01 22:09:06.608
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: I'm uninstalling the app center version and using flathub.

Comment: Follow this tutorial. [https://www.javahelps.com/2015/03/install-latest-eclipse-in-ubuntu.html